# Create function to iterate through object key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am playing around with binance API, im very new to javascript, the first section in my code

```
binance.prices((error, ticker) => {
console.log("prices()", ticker);
console.log("Price of BTC: ", ticker.BTCUSDT);
});
```

above code outputs:

```
 ETHBTC: '0.07421500',
 LTCBTC: '0.01994000',
 BNBBTC: '0.00110540',
 NEOBTC: '0.00853400',
 QTUMETH: '0.02604400',
```

the code below runs a check on an selected key (GTOBTC), I cant seem to be able to create a loop which takes the name from the keys above.

```
binance.depth("GTOBTC", (error, depth, symbol) => {
a = 0;
b = 0;

for (value in depth.bids){
    a += Number(value);
};

for (value in depth.asks){
    b += Number(value);
};

var c = a - b;
var d = (c / a) * 100;


if (d >= 2.0){
    console.log(symbol + " Percent ok");
    console.log(d);
} else {
    console.log(symbol + " percentage not sufficient");
}
})
```

output for code above:

```
GTOBTC percentage not sufficient
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Pro tip: buy a good js book and get a deep insight into a language before you try to code. And if you ask a question here, please try to understand them instead of copy + pasting the answers code.

Comment: can you provide a link for your API and the data that you get so we can answer your question ? , also you can try something with Ajax take a look at the map function their is lot off docu

Comment: Your console.log statements don't match what you say it outputs. You need to help us understand you data. Is that output the value of `ticker.BTCUSDT`? If so, how is that related to the rest of the question where you don't seem to be using the `ticker` object at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys) as below:

```
Object.keys(object).map((key) => { 
    console.log(object[key]) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or when you have jquery in web, u can use this:

```
$.each(object, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ' ' + value);     
});
```